# Как изменить стиль всплывающего сообщения у input

Tags: css3, html5

Если есть необходимость заполнения определенного поля в форме, ему дописывается required:

```html
<form action="">
    <div class="recoveryPassword">
        <p class="create_a_password">Придумайте новый пароль</p>
        <input type="password" id="input_view_password"  value="" placeholder="" required>
        <button class="view_password">Отправить</button>
    </div>        
</form>
```

и рядом с ним всплывает сообщение соответствующего вида: [image: screen message]

Как изменить стиль всплывающего сообщения у input?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, то никак, только писать свое всплывающее окно

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message